# c# sql statement display last 4 record

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to display the last 4 record of staff ID in each Label, what can I do???

```
String strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM staff";
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConn);
SqlDataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myDataReader.Read())
{
    Label1.Text = myDataReader["staffID"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = myDataReader["staffID"].ToString();
    Label3.Text = myDataReader["staffID"].ToString();
    Label4.Text = myDataReader["staffID"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use a query like that:

```
SELECT TOP 4 * 
FROM staff 
ORDER BY MyOrderColumn DESC
```

And with a query like that you will have the last 4 records returned to you.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to select only the last four if you want them only:

```
String strSQL = @"SELECT TOP 4 staffID FROM staff ORDER BY staffID DESC";
using(var myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConn))
using(var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand))
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(table);
    Label1.Text = table.Rows[0]["staffID"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = table.Rows[1]["staffID"].ToString();  
    Label3.Text = table.Rows[2]["staffID"].ToString();
    Label4.Text = table.Rows[3]["staffID"].ToString();
}
```

You have to handle the case that there are less than 4 staffs.

Comment: What if there are less than 4 rows?

Comment: @Tobsey: Added that as comment. I assume it's clear that he has to check `if(table.Rows.Count>=1)Label2.Text= ...`.

Answer (score 1):

If this is winforms you can try doing it this way:

```
int i = 1;
while (myDataReader.Read())
{
  var label = this.Controls.Find("Label" + i, false) as Label;
  if (label != null)
  {
      label.Text = myDataReader["staffID"].ToString();
  }
  else
  {
       break;
  }

  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try following:

```
  String strSQL = @"SELECT top 4 staffID FROM staff order by staffID desc";
  SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConn);
  SqlDataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

  var labels = new Label[] { Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4 };
  foreach (var label in labels) {
    if (!myDataReader.Read()) {
      break;
    }
    label.Text = myDataReader["staffID"].ToString();
  }
```

Also Repeater and databinding might be a better (cleaner) choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try Modifying the SQL Query which will return only last 4 Rows

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StaffID ORDER BY StaffID DESC) AS StaffID, *
FROM Staff
) as temporaryList
WHERE temporaryList.StaffID <= 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String strSQL = @"SELECT TOP 4 StaffID FROM staff ORDER BY StaffID DESC"; //
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConn);
SqlDataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
int i = 0;
while (myDataReader.Read() && i<4)
{
    Label lblToSet = new Label();
    switch (i) 
    {
       case 0: lblToSet = Label1; break;
       case 1: lblToSet = Label2; break;
       case 2: lblToSet = Label2; break;
       case 3: lblToSet = Label3; break;
    }
    lblToSet.Text = myDataReader["staffID"].ToString();
    i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With cte 
As 
(SELECT TOP 4 [StaffId]
   FROM [sample].[dbo].[Staff] 
  ORDER BY  [StaffId] desc) 

SELECT * 
  FROM cte 
 ORDER BY StaffId
```